# Why can't we ask questions about economics here?  Is there a place to ask questions about economics?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, allowed-topics, economics

Just as the title says. Finance are relevant to economy. Isn't true we need to understand economy to invest better?

Comment: Related: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/148/clarifying-the-area-51-proposal-can-some-basic-economics-and-policy-questions-be and http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/224/what-to-do-with-all-the-macroeconomics-questions.  In a nutshell, **some** basic economics questions are OK.  Other questions may be too theoretical or advanced for a personal finance site.

Comment: Furthermore, there is an **Economics** proposal at area 51.  See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics.  That site, when it launches, is likely to cater to the kind of more advanced economics questions we would tend to consider off-topic here.  (Likewise, Economics SE will probably see some basic questions related to personal finance that they will consider off-topic and better asked at Money SE.)

Comment: What is the point of creating 2 SE seperately for such closely related topics?

Comment: They are *not* so closely related, and the Economics site will be more academic/theory oriented.

Answer (score 12):

From the FAQ, regarding off-topic questions (emphasis added):

> *Academic* questions about economics or questions about economics that have *no bearing on personal finance*

In other words, this site is not the correct place for many questions that economics majors or economists would discuss.  It basically comes down to whether the topic is relevant to personal finance.

---

### Update!

The Economics Stack Exchange is now in **public beta**.  If you're interested in economics Q&A, you are encouraged to visit **[economics.stackexchange.com](http://economics.stackexchange.com)**.  Thank you.

Comment: economics.stackexchange.com is closed. But economy is strictly correlated to personal finance unless you think to live the rest of your life with gold under the mattress and writing Q/A about how to trade gold for food.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert on the rules here, but I think the reason why economics questions are separate from personal finance is because personal finance has lots of *practical* considerations that have little to do with the economy.

Questions about tax-advantaged savings accounts, cd laddering, home mortgages, budgeting, etc. are independent of the macroeconomic climate. Our society has an overwhelming number of personal finance options and terminology that you need to have a good understanding of just to be a responsible adult. The rules regarding taxes alone are insanely complicated. Mortgage terms and fees are also complicated. But all of these rules and knowledge have practical value.

If economic theory questions come into scope, then it will be much harder to find the practical Q&A discussions that we have now.

Comment: Well put.  Another way to look at it is that some economics topics have a bearing on personal finance.  Such topics are certainly welcome here.